# Form targeting iFrame on a different page

Tags: php, javascript, forms, iframe

for a client who insists on using his current setup, he has a form which on submission loads an asp file in an iframe.

As I've only been working in this field the past few years I have very little experience in using iFrames or ASP, so any help you could give me would be much appreciated.

The form is in sidebar.php...

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.vebra.com/home/quick/PFrefine.asp" name="searchform">
        <dl id="property_search">
          <dt class="bord">Bedrooms</dt>
          <dd><select name="bed" class="type1 Selectrooms">
                  <option selected="selected" value="1">0</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">2</option>
                  <option value="4">3</option>
                  <option value="5">4</option>
                  <option value="6">5</option>
              </select>
          </dd>

          <dt class="bord">Minimum Price</dt>
          <dd><select class="type2 SelectPrices" name="lop">
                <option value="0" selected>&#163;0</option>
                <option value="25000">&#163;25,000</option>
                <option value="50000">&#163;50,000</option>
                <option value="75000">&#163;75,000</option>
                <option value="100000">&#163;100,000</option>
                <option value="125000">&#163;125,000</option>
                <option value="150000">&#163;150,000</option>
                <option value="175000">&#163;175,000</option>
                <option value="200000">&#163;200,000</option>
                <option value="225000">&#163;225,000</option>
                <option value="250000">&#163;250,000</option>
                <option value="275000">&#163;275,000</option>
                <option value="300000">&#163;300,000</option>
                <option value="325000">&#163;325,000</option>
                <option value="350000">&#163;350,000</option>
                <option value="375000">&#163;375,000</option>
                <option value="400000">&#163;400,000</option>
                <option value="500000">&#163;500,000</option>
                <option value="600000">&#163;600,000</option>
                <option value="700000">&#163;700,000</option>
                <option value="800000">&#163;800,000</option>
                <option value="900000">&#163;900,000</option>
                <option value="1000000">&#163;1,000,000</option>
                <option value="2000000">&#163;2,000,000</option>
                <option value="3000000">&#163;3,000,000</option>
                <option value="4000000">&#163;4,000,000</option>
                <option value="5000000">&#163;5,000,000</option>
                <option value="6000000">&#163;6,000,000</option>
              </select>
          </dd>

          <dt class="bord">Maximum Price</dt>
          <dd><select name="hip" class="type3 SelectPrices">
                <option value="25000">&#163;25,000</option>
                <option value="50000">&#163;50,000</option>
                <option value="75000">&#163;75,000</option>
                <option value="100000">&#163;100,000</option>
                <option value="125000">&#163;125,000</option>
                <option value="150000">&#163;150,000</option>
                <option value="175000">&#163;175,000</option>
                <option value="200000">&#163;200,000</option>
                <option value="225000">&#163;225,000</option>
                <option value="250000">&#163;250,000</option>
                <option value="275000">&#163;275,000</option>
                <option value="300000">&#163;300,000</option>
                <option value="325000">&#163;325,000</option>
                <option value="350000">&#163;350,000</option>
                <option value="375000">&#163;375,000</option>
                <option value="400000">&#163;400,000</option>
                <option value="500000">&#163;500,000</option>
                <option value="600000">&#163;600,000</option>
                <option value="700000">&#163;700,000</option>
                <option value="800000">&#163;800,000</option>
                <option value="900000">&#163;900,000</option>
                <option value="1000000">&#163;1,000,000</option>
                <option value="2000000">&#163;2,000,000</option>
                <option value="3000000">&#163;3,000,000</option>
                <option value="4000000">&#163;4,000,000</option>
                <option value="5000000">&#163;5,000,000</option>
                <option selected value="6000000">&#163;6,000,000+</option>
              </select>
          </dd>
          <dt>Regions</dt><dd><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></dd>

          <dt><input type="checkbox" name="cou" id="couHertfordshire" value="43"/></dt><dd>Hertfordshire</dd>
          <dt><input type="checkbox" name="cou" id="couLondonNorth" value="126" /></dt><dd>London, North</dd>
          <dt><input type="checkbox" name="cou" id="couLondonNorthWest" value="127" /></dt><dd>London, North West</dd>

          <input type="hidden" name="slo" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="894" />
            <input type="hidden" name="bid" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="dbt" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="nre" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="thu" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="vto" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ord" value="undefined"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="nba" value="undefined" />

          <dt><input type="submit" class="search_now" value="Find Property" formtarget="hello" /></dt><dd><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></dd>
        </dl>
      </form>
```

And the results page i want to be in test.php...

```
<iframe width="583" height="500" name="hello">iframe</iframe>
```

Unfortunately I have no access to the ASP handler file at all.

Basically, when you fill in the form in the sidebar and click on the submit button I want the browser to redirect to the results page and load the iframe with the results.

Is that possible?

Comment: Oh the horror! Try `page.php#iframe_id` as the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page in the iFrame is capable of accepting GET as well as POST data, you can POST the data to the page containing the iFrame and then use your language of choice to append it to the src tag of the iFrame as a query string.

Alternatively, if the page in the iFrame will only accept POST data, e.g. because whoever wrote it has prevented it from accepting GET data for (perceived) security reasons, you can use your language of choice to write another form in the target page containing the iFrame, then auto-submit that (using JavaScript) to the iFrame, having set that form's target to be the iFrame. (Note that this is subtly different from the JQuery example above, which uses the query string.)

This is an example of the first solution above:

Form in first page:

```
<form name="frmPost" method="post" action="test_iframe_post_target.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="actionid" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="qy" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="123" />
</form>

<p><a href="javascript:document.frmPost.submit();">Submit Form</a></p>
```

Target Page:

```
<?php
$lngAction = $_POST["actionid"];
$lngQy = $_POST["qy"];
$lngPID = $_POST["pid"];
?>

<p>This is the target page. Action is: <?php echo $lngAction; ?></p>

<iframe name="test_iframe" width="900" height="320" src="test_iframe_post_iframe.php?action=<?php echo $lngAction; ?>&qy=<?php echo $lngQy; ?>&pid=<?php echo $lngPID; ?>" border="0" frameborder="0" align="center" marginwidth="1" marginheight="1" target="_top"></iframe>
```

iFrame:

```
<p>This is the iFrame. Action is: <?php echo $lngAction; ?>; Qy is: <?php echo $lngQy; ?>; PID is: <?php echo $lngPID; ?>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you just use ajax to post the form data. all under you control. enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a name on your iframe and then use the [target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#adef-target) attribute on the form.

```
<iframe src="foo" name="myframe"></iframe>
<form method="post" action="http://www.vebra.com/home/quick/PFrefine.asp" name="searchform" target="myframe">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using JavaScript and jQuery to read out a form and alter the url of an iframe accordingly:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="target" action="javascript:return false;">
  <input type="text" value="http://www.ftd.de" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<iframe id="iframe1" src="javascript:false;"></iframe>

<script>
$('#target').submit(function() {
  $('#iframe1').attr('src', $("input:first").val());
});    
</script>
</body>
```

Live demo:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snies/LDbFA/12/)